# Object.assign bug workaround

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, qtwebkit, polyfills

I run react-app in webkit (Qtwebkit) browser. App is written in es6 and transpiled into es5 with babel. I am getting an error in Qtwebkit browser only. I was able to find out that Object.assign implementation has a bug.

```
const x = Object.assign({}, {a: 1, b: 2});
//produces {"b":2}
```

I understand that I need to use polyfill for this function, but I am not sure how to do it properly. There is a native implementation which is bugy. I know how to use polyfill for my own modules. How can I force all external dependencies like React-router, etc. to use a new polyfill? Is there a way to set this in build process? I use webpack or gulp.

Comment: can always mod the polyfill to define `Object.assign2`...

Comment: What is your polyfill and have you filed a bug? It may be that the issue can just be fixed there and published quickly to resolve the issue. `babel-polyfill` uses `core-js` if that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I realized we used old version of QtWebKit. Upgrade solved the problem :)

Comment: We saw this behavior on one machine running Qt 4.8.6 and 5.2, but upgrading to 5.5.1 corrected the problem. However, another machine running 4.8.7 did not experience this behavior.   I believe the issue manifests in conjunction with core-js/shim , and only in certain conditions, which I was unable to narrow down completely.